# Dynamically shows consecutive weeks data(Sales)

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]Aryansena_0-1597818560619.png
Consider FA is my sales ,first column is date(week level granularity) and third column is week number. My req is as per FA slicer the table should interact and it will change but main prob what i m facing is if the week slicer(single select) selected anything consider 3 then where consecutive FA is not zero for three weeks ,that should show.

If week selected as 3 in table it should show 20,22,24 and 18,220,233,123,146.

if we select 4 week then 18,220,233,123,146.

now if we select FA between 220 and 233 nd weeks as 3 then blank table will be returned as there are no consecutive 3 weeks value in that range.

Comment: What if you select wk = 9

Comment: blank table will return

Comment: What is the logic for that? It will look for 9 consecutive non zero?

Comment: yes you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to achieve your requirement as below-

Considering your table name = "**consecutive**"

**Step-1:** to achieve the requirement, we have to separate the "wk" column to a different table. Go to the **Power Query Editor** and-

- Now just Duplicate your table "consecutive" and give it name "**consecutive slicer**".
- Keep only column "wk" in the new table and remove other columns.

Now we have 2 table.

**Step-2:** Remove any relation automatically established between two table from Model tab. Now get back to report by clicking "**Close & Apply**" button.

**Step-3:** Create your slicer using table "consecutive slicer". Enable Single Selection On for the slicer.

**Step-4:** Create the following measure in your table "consecutive"-

```
consecutive_non_zero_row_count = 

VAR selected_value = SELECTEDVALUE('consecutive slicer'[wk])
VAR current_row_date = MIN(consecutive[start date])
VAR current_row_fa = MIN(consecutive[fa])

VAR consecutive_count_start_date = 
IF (
    current_row_fa = 0,
    current_row_date,
    CALCULATE(
        MIN(consecutive[start date]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(consecutive),
            consecutive[start date] > 
                CALCULATE(
                    MAX(consecutive[start date]),
                    FILTER(
                        ALL(consecutive),
                        consecutive[start date] < current_row_date && consecutive[fa] = 0
                    )
                )
        )
    )
)

VAR consecutive_count_end_date = 
IF (
    current_row_fa = 0,
    current_row_date,
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(consecutive[start date]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(consecutive),
            consecutive[start date] < 
                IF(
                    CALCULATE(
                        MIN(consecutive[start date]),
                        FILTER(
                            ALL(consecutive),
                            consecutive[start date] > current_row_date && consecutive[fa] = 0
                        )
                    ) = BLANK(),
                    MAX(consecutive[start date].[Date]),
                    CALCULATE(
                        MIN(consecutive[start date]),
                        FILTER(
                            ALL(consecutive),
                            consecutive[start date] > current_row_date && consecutive[fa] = 0
                        )
                    )
                )
        )
    )
)

VAR row_count_between_start_and_end_date =
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        ALL(consecutive),
        consecutive[start date] >= consecutive_count_start_date && consecutive[start date] <= consecutive_count_end_date
    )
)

RETURN IF(
    current_row_fa = 0,
    0,
    IF(
        row_count_between_start_and_end_date >= SELECTEDVALUE('consecutive slicer'[wk]),
        1,
        0
    )
)
```

**Step-5:** Apply a visual level filter on your table visual as below-

[image]

Here is sample output for different selection in slicer-

[image]

Comment: looks good. let me try and let you know if it works.Thanks